# Memory leak reported by valgrind in dlopen?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, dlopen

I've been debugging some app lately with valgrind, and I'm getting very weird reports from `dlopen`.

```
==1987== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==1987==    at 0x4C24477: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:418)
==1987==    by 0x570F31F: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:142)
==1987==    by 0x570EEE0: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:88)
        <my call to dlopen>
==1987==
==1987== 264 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==1987==    at 0x4C25153: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==1987==    by 0x400CD44: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:506)
==1987==    by 0x4012DA2: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:326)
==1987==    by 0x400E385: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
==1987==    by 0x40126C6: _dl_open (dl-open.c:615)
==1987==    by 0x570EF65: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:67)
==1987==    by 0x400E385: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
==1987==    by 0x570F2AB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
==1987==    by 0x570EEE0: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:88)
        <my call to dlopen>
```

This looks like the error message that is initialized for `dlerror`, but looking at the man page, it doesn't say anything about how this should be cleared. Any idea how to correctly get rid of this?

Comment: yes, of course, I double-checked that dlclose is properly called -- but only if dlopen returns something != NULL, and I suspect this is from cases where dlopen _does_ return 0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Was able to reproduce this issue with some 'hello world' code, which doesn't even call any symbols in the loaded object.
http://pastebin.com/d690bea57

I assume it's a bug in libc or valgrind.
Reproducible on Ubuntu 9.04 and Scientific Linux 5.3 (20 and 32 bytes respectively).

EDIT (by Calmarius):

This trivial code reproduces the problem:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void* handle = 0;

    handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_NOW);
    dlclose(handle);    

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with this command:

```
gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -g -o stuff  main.c -ldl -lpthread
```

Even the latest valgrind 3.11 can reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.04

Upstream bug has been reported: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358980

Comment: A friend pointed out it's a bug in Valgrind.
https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=16007
See attached valgrind suppression file.

Comment: I found out valgrind will not report this leak if you end your code with pthread_exit(NULL), even if you aren't using pthreads at all. Maybe this can help someone. It might be less cumbersome than writing a valgrind suppression file.

Comment: I assume that the call to pthread_exit cleans up the thread local storage that is used to store the error text (so that it is multi-thread safe -- you simply need thread affinity between the calls to dlopen and dlerror).

Comment: -1 because the paste is gone.  (Otherwise, I would have edited it into the answer …)

Comment: The problem is reproducible also with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and valgrind-3.15.0.

Answer (score 4):

This suppression is better:

```
{
   Ignore dlopen bug.
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   fun:_dl_open
   ...
}
```

(Note that the "..." is part of the suppression and should be entered literally.)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this myself in all sorts of libs, using dlopen or not. I just assumed it was some magic implementation within the libs which tricked valgrind - or - these libs actually do have memory leaks in which case there's nothing I can do within *my* app.